# Can't render login page with Authlogic and Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem rendering the login page. I have followed this turtorial: http://www.dixis.com/?p=352 but in the views I use:

```
# app/views/user_sessions/new.html.erb
<h1>Login</h1>

<%= form_for @user_session, :as => :user_session, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @user_session %>
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %><%= f.label :remember_me %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.submit "Login" %>
<% end %>
```

But only the text "Login" shows. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 3

you need to change to this

```
<%= form_for @user_session, :as => :user_session, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you watch the post you will see that i already have done that. Any other suggestions? (i do have the equal sign)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see any post

Comment: can´t you see the text under ..the views I use: # app/views/user_sessions/new.html.erb?

Comment: Sorry but you were using <% form_for ..., while I was using <%= form_for... Please pay attention to the detail

Comment: Didn´t know how to edit the post but now i figured it out, i do have the equal sign.

Comment: Did you fix your issue am having the same problem!?